# PHP MySQL and Android connection

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I'm trying to connect my android app with an online database server that uses `MySQL` and `phpMyAdmin`.

But problem I am having is that I'm unable to access my database (which is online) using Java code for android.

It get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)

I already loaded the driver and external JAR of MySQL but it is still showing this exception.

The code is :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql:http://www.demo.com:2082/",
        "usernme", "password"); //username and password of cpanel access
PreparedStatement statement = con
        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '"
                + userName + "'");

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

while (result.next()) {
    retrievedUserName = result.getString("username");
    Log.e("data username:", retrievedUserName);
    retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Webservice` to make the Connection to Mysql from your android app through json or xml.you can use `SQlite` database to connect the android app internally by the use of this package `android.database.sqlite classes`

Comment: can you provide a sample code or link to any basic connectivity with MySQL?

Comment: refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: But can we connect without using PHP?

Comment: @Himanshu refer this link to create json http://www.9lessons.info/2012/08/java-json-jquery-display-records.html